# Update table if all results from multiple UNION queries is 0

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with stock from two different sellers.
If I can not source the product from any of these two sellers then I would like to set a value in another table to '0'.

First of all I am getting some required values from the two seller stock tables combined with a UNION

```
(SELECT A.`id`, B.`product_id`, A.`internal_id`, CASE WHEN A.`in_stock` = 'Stock available' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as `in_stock` FROM `pricing_dm` A LEFT JOIN `pricing_vendor_mapping` B ON A.`internal_id`= B.`internal_id` WHERE B.`vendor_id` = '1' AND B.`product_id` > '0'

UNION

SELECT A.`id`, B.`product_id`, A.`internal_id`, CASE WHEN A.`in_stock` = 'In Stock' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as `in_stock` FROM `pricing_m` A LEFT JOIN `pricing_vendor_mapping` B ON A.`internal_id`= B.`internal_id` WHERE B.`vendor_id` = '2' AND B.`product_id` > '0') t1
```

If I get a result like below where in_stock = 0 for both sellers then I would like to update another field with 0

```
id product_id internal_id in_stock
1  123        5555        0
1  123        4567        0
```

If I can source the product from one (like below) or both sellers then I don't want to do anything.

```
id product_id internal_id in_stock
1  123        5555        0
1  123        4567        1
```

Basically how can I check if all results for a product_id are 'in_stock = 0' and based on that do an update of another table.

Thank you

Comment: which table and which fild you want to set to 0. ist the also a product_id field

Comment: Hi. It is a complete different table but it is also using the product_id field.

Comment: I know how to do the update but I don't know how to check that all results per product_id are in_stock=0 ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are easier ways to do this if the tables can be joined, but You could get the max in_stock number and knowing that if it's over 0 you could do it with a CTE like this (I am not able to test this in mysql so it may need some syntax correction)

```
WITH CTE (in_stock) AS (
SELECT MAX(in_stock) from (
    (SELECT A.`id`, B.`product_id`, A.`internal_id`, CASE WHEN A.`in_stock` = 'Stock available' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as `in_stock` FROM `pricing_dm` A LEFT JOIN `pricing_vendor_mapping` B ON A.`internal_id`= B.`internal_id` WHERE B.`vendor_id` = '1' AND B.`product_id` > '0'

    UNION

    SELECT A.`id`, B.`product_id`, A.`internal_id`, CASE WHEN A.`in_stock` = 'In Stock' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as `in_stock` FROM `pricing_m` A LEFT JOIN `pricing_vendor_mapping` B ON A.`internal_id`= B.`internal_id` WHERE B.`vendor_id` = '2' AND B.`product_id` > '0') t1 ))

UPDATE some_table SET some_column = 0
where CTE.in_stock < 1
```

Comment: Hey Stickabee. Thank you for your solution. I have not tried it yet but will try it of course. If this will not work for me you had the idea to sum up all in_stock results for a product. If this is below 1 then I can do the update. So I guess I can solve it in any case but of course I will first try your solution.

Comment: Note that you'll need MySQL 8.0 or later to use Common Table Expressions (CTE) which usually means installing a version from Oracle instead of the community repository such as in Linux

Comment: You can also install MariaDB 10.3 to use CTE

Answer (score 0):

I used nested queries and a variable to meet your criteria.

See example DDL in this link:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8jUMnbEFpGWA4fmmP67yw9/0 I think this meets your requirements.

Here is my Query, with comments:

```
#check initial another table values
select * from another_table;

#check the given resultset
#there are 3 pairs, 
#2 of which meet the condition for not updating
#1 of the pairs meets the condition for doing the requested update
SELECT A.`id`, B.`product_id`, A.`internal_id`, CASE WHEN A.`in_stock` = 'Stock available' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as `in_stock` FROM `pricing_dm` A LEFT JOIN `pricing_vendor_mapping` B ON A.`internal_id`= B.`internal_id` WHERE B.`vendor_id` = '1' AND B.`product_id` > '0'

UNION

SELECT A.`id`, B.`product_id`, A.`internal_id`, CASE WHEN A.`in_stock` = 'In Stock' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as `in_stock` FROM `pricing_m` A LEFT JOIN `pricing_vendor_mapping` B ON A.`internal_id`= B.`internal_id` WHERE B.`vendor_id` = '2' AND B.`product_id` > '0';

#the requested update statement
set @chk1 := 0;
update another_table 
set crab_people = 0
where product_id in

#this nested query will return all product_id 
#that fits the criteria to update another_table
(select product_id_not_in_stock from
(select 
case 
    when product_id = @chk1 and in_stock = 0 then @chk1
    when product_id != @chk1 and in_stock = 0 then @chk1 := product_id
end as product_id_not_in_stock

from 
(SELECT A.`id`, B.`product_id`, A.`internal_id`, CASE WHEN A.`in_stock` = 'Stock available' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as `in_stock` FROM `pricing_dm` A LEFT JOIN `pricing_vendor_mapping` B ON A.`internal_id`= B.`internal_id` WHERE B.`vendor_id` = '1' AND B.`product_id` > '0'

UNION

SELECT A.`id`, B.`product_id`, A.`internal_id`, CASE WHEN A.`in_stock` = 'In Stock' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as `in_stock` FROM `pricing_m` A LEFT JOIN `pricing_vendor_mapping` B ON A.`internal_id`= B.`internal_id` WHERE B.`vendor_id` = '2' AND B.`product_id` > '0') as t1

order by product_id, in_stock DESC, internal_id) as t2
where product_id_not_in_stock is not null
group by product_id_not_in_stock
having count(product_id_not_in_stock) > 1);

#confirm the changes went though
#expect crab_people from another_table to be updated
#where the product id is not in stock from both tables: pricing_dm and pricing_m
select * from another_table;
```